# Weak Law of Large Number to Central Limit Theorem

Tags: probability, sample-size, convergence, central-limit-theorem, law-of-large-numbers

Consider a distribution with unknown mean μ and population standard deviation σ=30. Using the Weak Law of Large Numbers, what is the minimum sample size in order to attain a probability of at least 99% that the sample mean X bar will not deviate from the population mean μ by more than 6 units?

Comment: Answer: 30^2/(5^2(0.01)) = 3600

In the same question, how can I compute for a minimum sample size using CLT?
I'm a bit confused about finding the sample size in CLT.

Comment: The Weak Law doesn't provide any quantitative information of this sort.  The question therefore likely refers to somebody's *proof* of the Weak Law rather than to the Law itself.  One would guess the intention is for you to apply Chebyshev's Inequality, not the Weak Law.